An Arena/Bump Allocator in C
An arena allocator is a memory allocation technique used in computer programming where memory is allocated from
a pre-allocated block (arena) rather than individually requesting memory from the operating system.
Once allocated, memory within the arena typically remains allocated until the entire arena is deallocated,
simplifying memory management and reducing the risk of memory leaks.
Working:
The whole implementation is about 55 lines of code (besides the test run).
The API is straightforward: begin with arena_new() and end with arena_destroy(). Memory allocations are
made using arena_alloc(), without the need for manual deallocation or tracking. The arena dynamically resizes
as needed.
An example follows:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "arena.h"

int main(void) {
    // Create a new arena
    Arena *arena = arena_new();

    // Allocate memory within the arena
    int *data = arena_alloc(arena, sizeof *data);

    // Deallocate memory and destroy the arena
    arena_destroy(arena);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Code:
arena.h:
#ifndef ARENA_H
#define ARENA_H 1

#include <stddef.h>

#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define ATTRIB_NONNULL          __attribute__((nonnull))
#else
    #define ATTRIB_NONNULL          /**/
#endif

typedef struct arena Arena;

Arena *arena_new(void);
void *arena_alloc(Arena *arena, size_t alloc_size) ATTRIB_NONNULL;
void arena_destroy(Arena *arena); 

#endif                          /* ARENA_H */

arena.c:
#include "arena.h"

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* In C2X/C23 or later, nullptr is a keyword. */
/* Patch up C18 (__STDC_VERSION__ == 201710L) and earlier versions.  */
#if !defined(__STDC_VERSION__) || __STDC_VERSION__ <= 201710L
    #define nullptr ((void *)0)
#endif

#define ARENA_INITIAL_CAPACITY  10 * (size_t)1024

#define GROW_CAPACITY(capacity, initial) \
    ((capacity) < initial ? initial : (capacity) * 2)

struct arena {
    size_t count;
    size_t capacity;
    uint8_t pool[];
};

Arena *arena_new(void)
{
    Arena *a = calloc(1, sizeof *a + ARENA_INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof a->pool[0]);
    a->capacity = ARENA_INITIAL_CAPACITY;
    return a;
}

void *arena_alloc(Arena *arena, size_t alloc_size)
{
    if ((arena->count + alloc_size) >= arena->capacity) {
        arena->capacity =
            GROW_CAPACITY(arena->capacity, ARENA_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
        Arena *a = realloc(arena,
            sizeof *arena + arena->capacity * sizeof arena->pool[0]);

        if (a == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        arena = a;
    }

    void *result = arena->pool + arena->count;

    arena->count += alloc_size;
    return result;
}

void arena_destroy(Arena *arena)
{
    free(arena);
}

#ifdef TEST_MAIN

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    Arena *const arena = arena_new();

    if (arena == nullptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: arena_new(): failed to allocate memory.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int *a = arena_alloc(arena, sizeof *a);
    int *b = arena_alloc(arena, sizeof *b);
    int *c = arena_alloc(arena, sizeof *c);

    if (a == nullptr || b == nullptr || c == nullptr) {
        arena_destroy(arena);
        fprintf(stderr, "error: arena_alloc(): failed to allocate memory.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    *a = 1;
    *b = 2;
    *c = 3;
    
    printf("&a: %p, a: %d\n"
           "&b: %p, b: %d\n"
           "&c: %p, c: %d\n",
           (void *)a,
           *a, 
           (void *)b,
           *b, 
           (void *)c,
           *c);
    arena_destroy(arena);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#endif  /* TEST_MAIN */

Makefile:
CC := gcc-13

CFLAGS += -std=c2x
CFLAGS += -fPIC
CFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -Wextra
CFLAGS += -Wpedantic
CFLAGS += -Wwrite-strings
CFLAGS += -Wno-parentheses
CFLAGS += -Wpedantic
CFLAGS += -Warray-bounds
CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-function
CFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes

all: arena

test: CFLAGS += -DTEST_MAIN 
test: arena 

clean: 
    $(RM) arena

.PHONY: all test clean 
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

Building:
To build a sample program, simply do:
make test
./arena

For ease, here's the github link: An Arena Allocator in C
Review Request:
Possible optimizations, potential undefined/implementation-defined behavior, integer overflow/underflow, style et cetera.
Is the initial pool size okay? Should it be higher or lower?

I should have probably built the executable with make alone. make test sounds like I have tests.

Does it have to be thread safe?

@ghellquist Preferably, yes. But I only required something expandable and quick for some parsing code.

As written it is not threadsafe. If several threads use the library it might create nasty problems, the type that only occurs sometimes. In order to be threadsafe you need to protect the data with semaphores or other threadsafe techniques (there are several).

General
The code is nicely formatted, and the use of comments judicious. Thanks!
Tests?
There is a distinct lack of tests.
You do have a "brush" test, but it's quite insufficient in "depth". It doesn't test growth, doesn't test heterogeneous allocations (which may have caught the alignment issue), etc... I would advise writing a unit-test suite.
Documentation?
Documentation comments on the public API (header) would be more useful than comments on the function calls in main.
The fact that nullptr is returned on failure (instead of aborting) should be documented, even if it just follows malloc, for example.
Bug: realloc
(As also noted by @ComicSansMS)
The use of realloc is a terrible, terrible, mistake.
It means that if I have a pointer p allocated by arena_alloc and then at some point arena_alloc decides to call realloc (which I will never know) then using p afterwards will be Undefined Behavior.
You cannot use realloc. Instead you can:

Never grow the arena.
Keep a list of previous arena allocations, and add a new one as necessary.

I note that the typical approach is to never grow: the user can always create a new arena should they wish to, after all.
Bug: alignment
(As also noted by @Davislor)
The memory returned is not guaranteed to be aligned, leaving it to the user to do so.
You could simply align memory to alignof(max_align_t) as malloc does, it's as simple as just rounding up the allocation size to a multiple of it prior to bumping count.
Note, though, that with the rise of SIMD, many types are now more aligned than max_align_t (which cannot be changed for backward compatibility reason) and thus new C versions provide aligned_alloc instead.
I would advise following the new API. If anything, it means that you do get the benefit of packing memory more tightly, by not wasting up to alignof(max_align_t) - 1 bytes between allocations. For example when allocating two string buffers one after another. The added flexibility may add a slight cost to the call (a few instructions), though, so it's a trade-off.
Bug: overflow
Beware that the alloc_size argument passed to arena_alloc may be so large (consider SIZE_MAX) that arena->count + alloc_size may overflow, thereby wrapping around at 0 and returning a very small total, which may then compare less than arena->capacity.
Handling of overflow requires some care: using a > b - c rather than a + c > b is better, though that may require proving c <= b first.
API Improvements
There are two improvements which could be worthwhile:

Allow passing an initial size to the arena_new function, rather than picking an arbitrary one. The user is better placed to know how much they'll need.
Pass the alignment to arena_alloc, as discussed above.

Aside: good use of __attribute__((nonnull))!
API Additions
Some functions could be useful:

Array allocation: where element size and number of elements are passed separately, so the multiplication can be checked not to overflow.
Reallocation: by keeping track of the last size allocated, or by having the user supply the original size of the allocation to reallocate, you can detect whether it's the last, and if so extend in place instead of copying. Can be handy.
Reset: rather than having the user destroy and re-create a fresh arena, a reset function (which just resets count) is more efficient.

Considerations
It may be worth annotating arena_alloc with __attribute__((malloc)), instructing GCC that the returned pointer cannot alias any other pointer.
While in theory the arena pointer does point to a memory block which aliases with the return value, in practice the "allocated" block is not accessed via arena for the lifetime of the pointer, so this should be sound.
Putting it altogether
Core of header:
/* Bump allocator arena. */
typedef struct arena Arena;

/* Returns a new arena with the specific `capacity`.

   On allocation failure, returns `nullptr`. */
Arena *arena_new(size_t capacity);

/* Destroys the arena, freeing its memory.

   Any pointer allocated by this arena is invalidated. */
void arena_destroy(Arena *arena);

/* Resets the arena, invalidating all existing allocations.

   While existing pointers allocated by this arena are this valid as far as the
   language is concerned, they should be considered invalid as using them may
   cause Undefined Behavior. */
void arena_reset(Arena *arena) ATTRIB_NONNULL;

/* Allocates a pointer from the arena.

   The allocated pointer is at least aligned to `alignment`, and is valid until
   the arena is reset or destroyed.

   `alignment` must be a power of 2.

   `size` must be a multiple of `alignment`. */
void *arena_alloc(Arena *arena, size_t alignment, size_t size) ATTRIB_NONNULL;

Core of source:
struct arena {
    size_t count;
    size_t capacity;
    uint8_t pool[];
};

Arena *arena_new(size_t capacity)
{
    Arena *a = calloc(1, sizeof *a + capacity);
    a->capacity = capacity;
    return a;
}

void arena_destroy(Arena *arena)
{
    free(arena);
}

void arena_reset(Arena *arena)
{
    arena->count = 0;
}

void *arena_alloc(Arena *arena, size_t alignment, size_t size)
{
    assert(alignment == 1 || !(alignment & (alignment - 1)));
    assert(size / alignment * alignment == size);

    char* p = arena->pool + arena->count;

    uintptr_t original = ((uintptr_t) p);

    if (original > UINTPTR_MAX - alignment) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    /*
       Rounds up the pointer value to the next multiple of alignment.
    
       - With alignment being a power of 2, alignment - 1 is of the form 
         0b001..1.
       - Thus "x & !(alignment - 1)" rounds x down to the previous multiple of
         alignment.
       - And "(x + alignment - 1) & !(alignment -1)" rounds up.
    */
    uintptr_t aligned = (original + alignment - 1) & !(alignment - 1);

    size_t offset = aligned - original;

    if (size > SIZE_MAX - offset) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    size += offset;

    if (size > arena->capacity - arena->count) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    arena->count += size;

    /* Equal to "aligned", but preserves provenance */
    return p + offset;
}
```


About the overflow, is this: if (arena->count + alloc_size < alloc->count) || (arena->count + alloc_size >= arena->capacity)) { return nullptr; }; still brittle?

@Harith: That's an alternative. It's not necessarily clearer though, and it's arguably more brittle -- notably there's a risk of divergence between the left-hand and right-hand of ||. I wouldn't recommend it when a > b - c works.

Pointers returned by the allocator are not stable
Because you are using realloc for growing the heap, each call to arena_alloc will potentially invalidate all of the pointers you have given out before. This is highly unusual behavior for an allocator, and doubly so since it is very difficult for a user to predict when the reallocation will take place.
There's several ways to address this:
The easiest way is to just not allow growing the arena beyond the initial size.
A more advanced approach will keep allocating new regions of memory, potentially with a geometric growth factor for the size. This requires you to keep track of all the regions of memory managed by the arena, either by storing an array of pointers somewhere, or by having an intrusive linked list as part of the memory regions, where each region contains at a fixed offset a pointer to the previous region.

This is a very good point. I did advise not to use the global heap, but should have picked up on this.

Memory Alignment
Your implementation returns unaligned memory.  On some architectures, allocating a char followed by an int, and dereferencing the int*, will crash the program with a bus error.
If you don’t pass in the required alignment (as calloc() does), the only way for the allocator to work correctly is to always return a pointer aligned to alignof(max_align_t) (as malloc() does).
Using the Global Heap
A common use case for an arena allocator is to give multiple threads their own allocators that can be used without sharing the heap, which serializes the algorithm.  Another is to allocate objects from a specific region of memory, such as a memory-mapped file or device.
Even if you only needed something simpler, and your only purpose is to reduce the number of calls to the heap, you’d still want the user to be able to specify the size.
This implementation breaks that by always creating the arena on the global heap.  Each individual allocation could potentially lock the heap as well, since it calls realloc().
An arena allocator that always calls the global heap is useless.  Bypassing the global heap is what you want an arena allocator for!
Some alternatives you might consider:
Arena pool = ARENA_INITIALIZER; // Initializes a valid Arena of size 0.
/* ... */
pool = arena_resize(ARENA_SIZE); // Or whatever API you want.

char alignas(max_align_t) thread_local_arena[ARENA_SIZE]; // Stack-allocated.
// Does not use the global heap:
Arena pool = arena_new(thread_local_arena, sizeof(thread_local_arena));
/* The lifetime of the arena is the same as the lifetime of this thread procedure,
 * which is the lifetime of the thread.
 */

Arena* arena_ref = malloc(sizeof(struct arena));
assert(arena_ref); // Production code might want more complex error-handling.
*arena_ref = *arena_new();

Any of these gives the user more flexibility to allocate the arena and its control block.
Another approach is what K&R did in their (wholly obsolete now) implementation of malloc(): store the control block at the beginning of the allocated memory, add its size to the pointer you return, and subtract the right number of bytes from the pointer you’re passed back to get the pointer to the control block.
The Makefile
You add -Wpedantic twice, and neither target, optimization nor debugging flags.  You generally are compiling either a debug or a release build.  I normally add -Wconversion -Wdeprecated.  There is also no need to add flags one at a time.

"Your implementation returns unaligned memory." ==> Oops. I fooled myself by saying that malloc() would take of that. I was very mistaken. Thank you.

"There is currently no way to deallocate and re-use any part of the arena." ==> Are we talking about something like a arena_reset() function which simply sets the count member to 0?

@Harith That either, but I meant, there’s no arena_free.

@Harith Also, fixed that one of my snippets didn’t properly align the arena either (although it’d be valid if I were only allocating unaligned memory).

@Harith On second thought, I deleted that remark. It’s outside the scope of your project.

Prior to C11, is it possible to replace max_align_t with the maximum alignment requirement of intmax_t, long double, void *, and void (*)()?

@Harith I don’t believe there’s anything in C99 requiring that to work. You might, for instance, want naturally-aligned 128-bit vectors on an implementation with 64-but intmax_t. And C89 did not even have intmax_t.

debug
The contract
between caller and library goes two ways.

Library promises to deliver a unique pointer to memory of proper size N.
Caller promises to color within the lines, from 0 .. N-1, not accessing the [-1] or the [N]th byte.

When caller creates new arena with a debug flag turned on,
the library might take additional actions for each alloc().
The idea is to make buggy calling code behave in a more
obviously buggy way.
alignment
We probably want to return memory blocks
that obey some alignment restriction.
Simplest approach would be to let caller specify
that when creating an arena, or on each alloc request.
bookkeeping
You currently pack user memory requests together as tightly
as possible, taking advantage of the lack of an alignment requirement.
Consider inserting enough padding bytes between user blocks so you can

insert one or more guard bytes before beginning,
insert guard byte(s) just after end,
pad to satisfy alignment,
remember the size of this block, and
maybe thread this block to adjacent ones.

So mixed in with user storage we have overhead (length) storage
that you own, plus guard storage that you own,
which user must not access.
enforcement
Write something along the lines of
0xDeadBeef
to the guard bytes upon each allocation.
On each arena_alloc() call,
and perhaps whenever a paranoid app calls arena_check() for debugging,
you could perform zero or more guard checks.
Read the guards before and after a given user block to verify
they still say 0xDeadBeef or are otherwise intact.
Write new values there, perhaps 0xBeefDead or a counter,
so caller will realize they cannot rely on that storage.
It is important that bytes immediately before a user block,
and especially the bytes immediately following such a block,
should be non-zero. The idea is to trigger
OBOB
failures for inappropriate app use of strlen() or strnlen(),
which keep forging ahead till encountering ascii NUL.
It might seem sensible to pad with zeros until alignment
boundary, but that actually does app developers a disservice.
It would be better if they noticed their bugs more quickly.
